# Cloning a tree in git

Tags: git, tree, clone

I am new to git.

I have accidentally removed part of the history for our project on git. Now, I want to set the head to the latest stable release. The issue is the tree to which i want to set the HEAD to is not accessible from it commands, but i can access it through browser.

Does anybody know how to clone a specific tree using its SHA?

I have tried git reset SHA, but the SHA is not recognized.
I have also tried `git clone -b SHA repo.git`, but it did not work either.

Comment: How did you remove "part of the history"?

Comment: Are there other copies of the repository, besides the one on the server and your local one? (i.e. did someone else clone it before?)

Comment: Does your repository use any submodules? (Is there a file `.gitmodules`?)

Comment: What kind of Server are you accessing through your browser? (github?) - Please update your question with all those details.

Answer (score 7):

You mix up different concepts.

Whenever you clone, you clone a whole **repository**. (There is no way to clone a specific "tree".)

A repository mainly consist of many **commits**. Those are the ones you can checkout. Each commit knows its parent commit - this forms a history **tree**.

A commit itself contains a directory **tree** with all the files.

---

Usually there is some kind of server hosting the "central" repository.

You first clone your repository. This will create a complete copy of that central repository on your host. (With all the branches and commits.)

Afterwards you usually only interact with your local repository.

---

From you error message (unfortunately hidden only in some  comment) it seems like your projects might use submodules. (A way of including a completely different repository in your project.)

This tends to be a bit tricky. Have a look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules.

Answer (score 4):

Has this "latest stable release" already pushed to the server? If yes, you can run a `git fetch` and `git checkout SHA`.

If this particular commit is only in your local history, do a `git reflog` and identify the commit. Then checkout the desired commit.